# Changing style of button generated from code behind displayed using panel

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, pagination, paging

Here is my code used to generate paging buttons in asp.net but would like to change the style of the buttons to match that of Bootstrap's pagination class. How could I do this as the buttons are generated from code behind? Here is the Code behind C#:

```
private void AddpagingButton()
        {
            // this method for generate custom button for Custom paging in Gridview
            int totalRecord = 0;
            int noofRecord = 0;
            totalRecord = ViewState["TotalRecord"] != null ? (int)ViewState["TotalRecord"] : 0;
            noofRecord = ViewState["NoOfRecord"] != null ? (int)ViewState["NoOfRecord"] : 0;
            int pages = 0;
            if (totalRecord >0 && noofRecord > 0)
            {
                // Count no of pages 
                pages = (totalRecord / noofRecord) + ((totalRecord % noofRecord) > 0 ? 1 : 0);
                for (int i = 0; i < pages; i++)
                {
                    Button b = new Button();
                    b.Text = (i + 1).ToString();
                    b.CommandArgument = (i + 1).ToString();
                    b.ID = "Button_" + (i + 1).ToString();
                    b.Click += new EventHandler(this.b_click);
                    Panel1.Controls.Add(b);
                }
            }

        }
```

And here is the simple panel component in the front end:

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
```

Comment: is this webforms?

Comment: Yes, this is webforms.